# How can my facebook app send me an inbox or email?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, heroku

I am using heroku, php and javascript, I am a complete newb.

I have a facebook app that asks the user for their name, birthday and email address. I want this information emailed or inboxed to me or better yet create an event on my xxxbirthdays calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook can't send emails for you.  You'll have to implement sending emails in your server side code.  Easiest to use the built in [php `mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Friend's birthdays already appear on your calendar, but here is the documentation for creating events -

- on behalf of a user - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events
- on behalf of a page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events